# Bootstrap JS Modal

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I send a link for forgotten password to the client. I want to show a bootstrap JS modal for changing password when the client clicks the link.
The code showing my approach is provided below:

> account.html

```
   <template name="ResetPassword">

  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal-9" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">


          <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <span class="f-s-20 text-blue">ŞİFRE DEĞİŞTİRME EKRANI </span>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                {{#if resetPassword}}
                <form action="/reset-password"  id="resetPasswordForm" method="post">
                    <input id="resetPasswordPassword" name="password" placeholder="New Password" type="password" >
                    <input id="resetPasswordPasswordConfirm" name="password-confirm" placeholder="Confirm" type="password" >
                    <input class="btn-submit" id="resetpasswordbtn" type="submit" value="Reset">
                </form>
          {{/if}}
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Kapat</button>
              </div>
          </div>

      </div>
  </div>

</template>
```

account.js

```
Accounts.onResetPasswordLink(function (token, done) {
    Session.set('resetPasswordToken', token);
$($(this).data("#myModal-9")).show();

    done();
});
```

Comment: Please describe what you have done so far, along with its outcome. Have you looked at the official Bootstrap JS docs?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code.

```
$("#myModal-9").modal('show');
```

Comment: thank you for reply but unfortunately it doesn't work